# Restricting php endpoints with AWS apigateway

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have backend API written in the laravel framework. Every client request goes through a single AWS api-gateway. This gateway only verifies the users identity(authenticates) and proxies it to the php backend API. Gateway does not have API for each resources like user, product, order etc. I have two types of users in AWS user pool. Admin and normal users. Now, I want to restrict certain php API endpoints (edit, delete) to the non admin users. 
One way of doing this is to maintain the user information with their role and permission in the database and handle logic in the php code itself. While I am reading AWS documentation, it says it can control the access to the API. As I have already mentioned I don't have separate api-gateway for each resources, I don't know if it is possible to control access in the gateway itself. Can somebody help me which approach should i use. Is maintaining RBAC logic in the php code the right approach or just overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way might be to go with standard IAM roles and policies: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

> To allow an API caller to invoke the API or refresh its caching, you must create IAM policies that permit a specified API caller to invoke the API method for which the IAM user authentication is enabled. The API developer sets the method's authorizationType property to AWS_IAM to require that the caller submit the IAM user's access keys to be authenticated. Then, you attach the policy to an IAM user representing the API caller, to an IAM group containing the user, or to an IAM role assumed by the user.

You can find more information in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html), but here is an IAM policy example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Permission",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Execution-operation"           
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage/METHOD_HTTP_VERB/Resource-path"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```